# How to highlight dock mouseover faster? GNOME

Tags: gnome, mouse, unity-dash

While hovering my mouse over apps in the dock (favorites or current active apps) the highlighting is very slow compared to Windows 10. Even hovering over Firefox tabs is kinda slow.
I use GNOME.
Is there a way to make the highlighting more sensitive?

[GIF with Ubuntu dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkOJX.gif)

[GIF with Windows dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHLbH.gif)

Comment: Try using [Peek](https://github.com/phw/peek) to record your video, otherwise is very hard to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I have added recordings from both OSs. The GIF from Ubuntu is a bit laggy, but the highlighting is truly slower compared to Windows. Unfortunately, I did not check how it was before all the modifications and extensions I applied, but as I remember, the default dock was still the same.